# zooming child views without using View.onDraw and canvas.setMatrix

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, multi-touch, pinchzoom

Is it possible to set a matrix onto a ViewGroup or Layout so that all children are automatically affected? For instance, if you got a layout like this:

1. MainActivity - RelativeLayout

   - ViewGroup - RelativeLayout
   - ImageView
   - LayeredDrawable

So it should be possible to implement Zoom/Pan in the ViewGroup so that both, the ImageView and the LayeredDrawable (children of the ViewGroup) are affected. I want to avoid using View.OnDraw (that is used in ALL examples on pinch-zoom).

Any idea?

Comment: for ViewGroup you actually use dispatchDraw as onDraw by default is not called

Comment: And then the matrix that is set on the canvas (argument of onDraw) will affect all children during dispatchDraw?

Comment: they will be drawn according to the Matrix but their bounds will not change

Comment: Then a likely touch event on one of the children won't be processed correctly. For instance if the parent says rotate by 45 degrees then the child is drawn correctly but the user still needs to touch at 0 degrees then?

Comment: but see MotionEvent.transform(Matrix)

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Comment: No. I ended up using a Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check getChildStaticTransformation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildStaticTransformation(android.view.View,android.view.animation.Transformation)
It's a callback that gets called for every child of a viewgroup and allows you to set a transformation to the child

Comment: Cool. That looks perfect. I will check that out. I found a nice [example](http://zvolodymyr.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/viewgroupgetchildstatictransformation.html) for that.

Comment: btw it will only draw children with respect to the Matrix but still doesnt change children bounds, so its luke overriding dispatchDraw

Comment: Well actually changing view bounds expecially on Android prior to 3.0 is something you should always avoid since is a very expensive operation for the rendering/layout system